# Problem with removing "NaN" values from an array

Tags: pine-script

I have problem to remove "NaN" values from an array(SRprices) and only hold numbers. (line 173)
I don't know my code works or not because I can't print the new array in table like I did for first array. (only last section should be check)

- I have two table, first one for base array which include NaN value
  second table is to print new array which have only numbers but don't work!

I think problem comed from array.size but why?! I don't know
I will appreciate if anyone help me

[Array values in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxF1G.png)

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © MoriFX

//@version=5
indicator('Dynamic Sup/Res lines Indicator', overlay=true, precision=4)

/////////               Parameters Input
pivotVal = input.int(10, title='Period for Pivot Points', minval=10)
loopbkPeriod = input.int(284, title='Loopback Period', minval=100, maxval=500)
SRstrength = input.int(3, title='S/R strength', minval=1)
ChannelW = input.int(10, title='Channel Width %', minval=5)
label_location = input.int(10, title='Label Location +-', tooltip='0 means last bar. for example if you set it -5 then label is shown on last 5. bar. + means future bars')
linestyle = input.string('Dotted', title='Line Style', options=['Solid', 'Dotted', 'Dashed'])
LineColor = input(color.blue, title='Line Color')
drawhl = input(true, title='Draw Highest/Lowest Pivots in Period')
showpp = input(false, title='Show Point Points')


/////////               Pivot points 
ph = ta.pivothigh(pivotVal, pivotVal)
pl = ta.pivotlow(pivotVal, pivotVal)
plotshape(ph and showpp, text='PH', style=shape.labeldown, color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.red, 0), location=location.abovebar, offset=-pivotVal)
plotshape(pl and showpp, text='PL', style=shape.labelup, color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.new(color.lime, 0), location=location.belowbar, offset=-pivotVal)

/////////               Support / Ressitant levels
sr_levels = array.new_float(21, na)

loopbkPeriodhighest = ta.highest(loopbkPeriod)
loopbkPeriodlowest = ta.lowest(loopbkPeriod)
cwidth = (loopbkPeriodhighest - loopbkPeriodlowest) * ChannelW / 100

aas = array.new_bool(41, true)  //availability of the PPs
// last privot points have more priority to be support/resistance, so we start from them
// if we met new Pivot Point then we calculate all supports/resistances again
u1 = 0.0
u1 := nz(u1[1])
d1 = 0.0
d1 := nz(d1[1])
highestph = 0.0
lowestpl = 0.0
highestph := highestph[1]
lowestpl := lowestpl[1]
if ph or pl
    //old S/Rs not valid anymore
    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_levels) - 1 by 1
        array.set(sr_levels, x, na)

    highestph := loopbkPeriodlowest
    lowestpl := loopbkPeriodhighest
    countpp = 0  // keep position of the PP
    for x = 0 to loopbkPeriod by 1
        if na(close[x])
            break
        if not na(ph[x]) or not na(pl[x])  // is it PP?
            highestph := math.max(highestph, nz(ph[x], loopbkPeriodlowest), nz(pl[x], loopbkPeriodlowest))
            lowestpl := math.min(lowestpl, nz(ph[x], loopbkPeriodhighest), nz(pl[x], loopbkPeriodhighest))
            countpp += 1
            if countpp > 40
                break
            if array.get(aas, countpp)  // if PP is not used in a channel
                upl = (ph[x] ? high[x + pivotVal] : low[x + pivotVal]) + cwidth
                dnl = (ph[x] ? high[x + pivotVal] : low[x + pivotVal]) - cwidth
                u1 := countpp == 1 ? upl : u1
                d1 := countpp == 1 ? dnl : d1
                // to keep the PPs which will be in current channel
                tmp = array.new_bool(41, true)

                cnt = 0  // keep which pivot point we are on
                tpoint = 0  // number of PPs in the channel 
                for xx = 0 to loopbkPeriod by 1
                    if na(close[xx])
                        break
                    if not na(ph[xx]) or not na(pl[xx])
                        chg = false
                        cnt += 1
                        if cnt > 40
                            break
                        if array.get(aas, cnt)  // if PP not used in other channels
                            if not na(ph[xx])
                                if high[xx + pivotVal] <= upl and high[xx + pivotVal] >= dnl  // PP is in the channel?
                                    tpoint += 1
                                    chg := true
                                    chg

                            if not na(pl[xx])
                                if low[xx + pivotVal] <= upl and low[xx + pivotVal] >= dnl  // PP is in the channel?
                                    tpoint += 1
                                    chg := true
                                    chg
                        // set if PP is used in the channel
                        if chg and cnt < 41
                            array.set(tmp, cnt, false)

                if tpoint >= SRstrength  // met enough PP in the channel? mark the PP as used for a channel and set the SR level
                    for g = 0 to 40 by 1
                        if not array.get(tmp, g)
                            array.set(aas, g, false)

                    if ph[x] and countpp < 21
                        array.set(sr_levels, countpp, high[x + pivotVal])
                    if pl[x] and countpp < 21
                        array.set(sr_levels, countpp, low[x + pivotVal])

setline(level) =>
    LineStyle = linestyle == 'Solid' ? line.style_solid : linestyle == 'Dotted' ? line.style_dotted : line.style_dashed
    _ret = line.new(bar_index - 1, level, bar_index, level, color=LineColor, width=2, style=LineStyle, extend=extend.both)
    _ret

if ph or pl
    var line highest_ = na
    var line lowest_ = na
    line.delete(highest_)
    line.delete(lowest_)
    if drawhl  //////////       Highest PH/PL price line
        highest_ := line.new(bar_index - 1, highestph, bar_index, highestph, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=extend.both)
        lowest_ := line.new(bar_index - 1, lowestpl, bar_index, lowestpl, color=color.purple, style=line.style_dashed, width=1, extend=extend.both)
        lowest_

    var sr_lines = array.new_line(21, na)
    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_lines) - 1 by 1
        line.delete(array.get(sr_lines, x))
        if array.get(sr_levels, x)
            array.set(sr_lines, x, setline(array.get(sr_levels, x)))
            
// set new labels if changed
var sr_levs = array.new_float(21, na)
if ph or pl
    for x = 0 to array.size(sr_levs) - 1 by 1
        array.set(sr_levs, x, array.get(sr_levels, x))

/////////////////////            define and delete old labels
label hlabel = na
label llabel = na
label.delete(hlabel[1])
label.delete(llabel[1])
var sr_labels = array.new_label(21, na)
bool resistance_broken = false
bool support_broken = false
float r_s_level = na

///////////////////                          set labels
for x = 0 to array.size(sr_labels) - 1 by 1
    label.delete(array.get(sr_labels, x))
    if array.get(sr_levs, x)
        if close[1] <= array.get(sr_levs, x) and close > array.get(sr_levs, x)
            resistance_broken := true
            r_s_level := array.get(sr_levs, x)
            r_s_level
        if close[1] >= array.get(sr_levs, x) and close < array.get(sr_levs, x)
            support_broken := true
            r_s_level := array.get(sr_levs, x)
            r_s_level
        lab_loc = close >= array.get(sr_levs, x) ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down
        array.set(sr_labels, x, label.new(x=bar_index + label_location, y=array.get(sr_levs, x), text=str.tostring(math.round_to_mintick(array.get(sr_levs, x))), color=color.lime, textcolor=color.black, style=lab_loc))

hlabel := drawhl ? label.new(x=bar_index + label_location + math.round(math.sign(label_location)) * 20, y=highestph, text='Highest PH : ' + str.tostring(highestph), color=color.silver, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down) : na
llabel := drawhl ? label.new(x=bar_index + label_location + math.round(math.sign(label_location)) * 20, y=lowestpl, text='Lowest PL : ' + str.tostring(lowestpl), color=color.silver, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up) : na


////////////////   table for printing S/R Levels

var table SRlevs = table.new(position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = array.size(sr_levs),
 bgcolor = color.rgb(210,210,210),  border_width = 2, border_color = color.white, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 2)

for xii = 0 to array.size(sr_levs) - 1
    table.cell(table_id = SRlevs, column = 0, row = xii , text_size=size.small, 
     text =str.tostring(array.get(sr_levs, xii)))

SRprices = array.new_float(array.size(sr_levs))
for xi = 0 to array.size(sr_levs) - 1 
    array.set(SRprices, xi, array.get(sr_levs, xi))

for k = 0 to array.size(sr_levs) - 1
    if  (na(array.get(SRprices, k)))
        array.remove(SRprices, k)

///     code for printing new array in table which not work!!
// var table SRtable = table.new(position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = array.size(SRprices),
//  bgcolor = color.rgb(210,210,210),  border_width = 2, border_color = color.white, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 2)

// for xii = 0 to array.size(SRprices) - 1
//     table.cell(table_id = SRtable, column = 0, row = xii , text_size=size.small, 
//      text =str.tostring(array.get(SRprices, xii)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `array.copy()` instead of a loop to duplicate your array.

You have to traverse the array from the opposite direction, otherwise when you remove an array element, the size of the loop will end up trying to reference a now non existent array element as the size of the array will no longer match the number of iterations of your loop.

You have a var declared table which uses the array size of `SRprices` as the number of rows. On the first bar this is likely to be zero, so on subsequent bars, it won't be modified when there are more values. Either set the size to the max needed or use `array.size(sr_levs)` which you declare with a size (of 21).

```
////////////////   table for printing S/R Levels

var table SRlevs = table.new(position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = array.size(sr_levs),
 bgcolor = color.rgb(210,210,210),  border_width = 2, border_color = color.white, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 2)

for xii = 0 to array.size(sr_levs) - 1
    table.cell(table_id = SRlevs, column = 0, row = xii , text_size=size.small, 
     text =str.tostring(array.get(sr_levs, xii)))

SRprices = array.copy(sr_levs)

for k = array.size(SRprices) -1 to 0
    if  (na(array.get(SRprices, k)))
        array.remove(SRprices, k)

var table SRtable = table.new(position.bottom_right, columns = 1, rows = array.size(sr_levs),
     bgcolor = color.rgb(210,210,210),  border_width = 2, border_color = color.white, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 2)

table.clear(SRtable, 0, 0, 0, 20)
if array.size(SRprices) > 0
    for xii = 0 to array.size(SRprices) - 1
        table.cell(table_id = SRtable, column = 0, row = xii , text_size=size.small, 
         text =str.tostring(array.get(SRprices, xii)))
```

Comment: Hi again, now i want to check cross on close and each one of SRprices array in a loop with bellow code. But doesn't work accurate and I think it's because of cross function in loop which is not recommended by pine script. Is there alternative solution? Thanks    'SRtouch = false
if array.size(SRprices) > 0
    for z = 0 to array.size(SRprices) - 1
        if ta.cross(close, array.get(SRprices, z))
        // if (close == array.get(SRprices, z))
            SRtouch := true
// ta.cross(close, array.get(SRprices, z))
bgcolor(color= SRtouch ? color.new(color.fuchsia, 75) : na)'

Comment: yes, it's not recommended to use certain functions within local scopes like if blocks. You can alternatively use open and close to check for price crossing. For example `(open < array.get(SRprices, z) and close > array.get(SRprices,z)) or (open > array.get(SRprices, z) and close < array.get(SRprices, z))`

Comment: Thanks bro. really helpful